# kelp buy-sell AMOUNT parameter

Tags: trade, kelp

Please help me figure out the buy-sell strategy with stablecoin.

Everything works fine, but the order amounts are all the same, how do I change this parameter:

```
AMOUNT = 100.0 # multiple of base amount = 10.0 * 100 units of base asset
```

Here are examples, what needs to be changed in the AMOUNT line?

```
SPREAD = 0.00575 # distance from mid price = 0.575%, i.e. bid / ask spread = 1.15%
AMOUNT = 100.0 # multiple of base amount = 10.0 * 100 units of base asset

# second level
[[LEVELS]]
SPREAD = 0.00785 # distance from mid price = 0.785%, i.e. bid / ask spread = 1.57%
AMOUNT = 100.0 # multiple of base amount = 10.0 * 100 units of base asset

# third level
[[LEVELS]]
SPREAD = 0.00875 # distance from mid price = 0.875%, i.e. bid / ask spread = 1.75%
AMOUNT = 100.0 # multiple of base amount = 10.0 * 100 units of base asset

# fourth level
[[LEVELS]]
SPREAD = 0.0099 # distance from mid price = 0.99%, i.e. bid / ask spread = 1.98%
AMOUNT = 100.0 # multiple of base amount = 10.0 * 100 units of base asset

# fifth level
[[LEVELS]]
SPREAD = 0.011 # distance from mid price = 1.1%, i.e. bid / ask spread = 2.2%
AMOUNT = 100.0 # multiple of base amount = 10.0 * 100 units of base asset
```

Answer (score 1):

Each level has the `AMOUNT` parameter.
If you want each level to have increasing sizes (for example) then you can adjust the appropriate `AMOUNT` parameter for each level.

There is also the `AMOUNT_OF_A_BASE` param which is multiplied by each of these `AMOUNT` params to arrive at the final base value amount at each level. The purpose of the `AMOUNT_OF_A_BASE` is to help you easily scale up/down all your orders with only one config change.

Hope this is helpful.